# Nifi Cluster reading duplicate data from kafka

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a cluster running with 6 nodes. Now when I add a Kafka consumer, each cluster node should pull unique data, as in each node should fetch from a diff partition: https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/09/15/apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka.

The same is also mentioned in the nifi docs. However in our case each node is pulling the same data from Kafka leading to duplication. Can someone please help. Are there any specific configurations required to get the same done?

Comment: Do your consumers belong to different consumer groups?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: No, the consumer ID will be the same as nifi replicates a processor accross the cluster. But as mentioned in nifi documentation, it should take care of fetching from different partitions.

Comment: Consumer ID is different to consumer group ID.

Comment: Also, how many partitions and active consumers do you have?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: I meant the consumer group id is the same

Comment: How do you know it is getting duplicate data?

Comment: Will be deleting the question, the issue was that when we were seeing the queues on each instance, they were showing duplicate data, however once we persisted this data into a db, we didnt get any duplicate records. The UI data confused use.

Comment: @BryanBende: If possible can you please take a look at: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/227178/unable-to-add-a-node-to-nifi-cluster.html , its a nifi related issue and we are stuck on it.